# Change relative path to full in css

Tags: php, css, absolute-path

I am using simple html dom to extract data from a website and pharse it. I cannot however change one of the realative paths in the style tag to a full one. I have tried many combinations.

I found a post here to use a PEAR script with simple html dom and it has worked on all links except below.

```
require_once 'includes/URL2.php';

$uri = new Net_URL2('http://www.stormcinemas.ie'); // URI of the resource
$baseURI = $uri;

foreach ($htmlcss->find('background[url]') as $elem) {
    $elem->url = $baseURI->resolve($elem->url)->__toString();
}

foreach ($html->find('*[src]') as $elem) {
    $elem->src = $baseURI->resolve($elem->src)->__toString();
}
foreach ($html->find('*[href]') as $elem) {
    if (strtoupper($elem->tag) === 'BASE') continue;
    $elem->href = $baseURI->resolve($elem->href)->__toString();
}
foreach ($html->find('form[action]') as $elem) {
    $elem->action = $baseURI->resolve($elem->action)->__toString();
}
```

style.css

```
<style> 
div.spriteImgSmall { background: url(/images/css_sprites/film_sprites/smallimages_sprite.jpg); } 
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was provided here but was deleted unfortunately. Thanks again, it actualy did solve my question.

Here it is for future ref.

```
$htmlcss = preg_replace('/url\(\s*[\'"]?\/?(.+?)[\'"]?\s*\)/i', 'url('.
        $baseURI.'/$1)', $htmlcss);
```

I would still be interested if someone know's how to use simple html dom on css as there is nothing anywhere on the net. It may not even be possible.