# simple_html_dom and Net_URL2 to normalize relative paths

Tags: php, relative-path, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to normalize relative paths to full urls using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and [Net_URL2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/), paths like this `src="/my_path"` are normalized by a script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419528/change-relative-path-to-full-in-css) but paths like this: `src="my_path"` are not! How to normalize paths like these?

Example:

```
$uri = new Net_URL2("http://test.com");
print $uri->resolve('/my_path') . "\n"; // works
print $uri->resolve('my_path') . "\n";  // doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a known bug in Net_URL2: http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19176

The ticket has a patch that fixes it, but it has not yet been fixed in the pear package itself. Patch:

```
Index: Net/URL2.php
===================================================================
--- Net/URL2.php    (revision 323857)
+++ Net/URL2.php    (revision )
@@ -720,7 +720,7 @@
                     } else {
                         // Merge paths (RFC 3986, section 5.2.3)
                         if ($this->_host !== false && $this->_path == '') {
-                            $target->_path = '/' . $this->_path;
+                            $target->_path = '/' . $reference->_path;
                         } else {
                             $i = strrpos($this->_path, '/');
                             if ($i !== false) {
```